# boost.log v2, how to get the current log file name

Tags: c++, boost-log, boost-logging

I'm updating a C++ class wrapping the boost logger to use a recent boost version with the logger v2 API.

Most of the work have been done, but with the logger v1 we used an API to get the current log file name and path like in the example below:

```
boost::filesystem::path p = pAsyncFileSink->locked_backend()->get_log_filename()
```

I searched for some hour, but I don't find a way to do that with the current API ! if we use a rotating text file backend, how to get the latest or in use file name ?

Any help or advice will be welcome.
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to obtain the current file name. You can see in the implementation that the file name is generated only when file rotation is performed, making it possible for the sink to not have a file name in certain points in time.

Comment: Ok thanks, I had a look by myself to see how the text_file_backend is implemented and now I'm quite sure that the only way for me to get back that functionality is to patch boost log, because there is no signal or class that we can inject to get the current file name or path in which we/logger is writing (I thought that a customized file collector could be a good idea but it's not because a collector receive a new file info only when the file is close....) ! it's a missing feature :)